# lubuntu won't display on both monitors at the same time

Tags: 13.10, multiple-monitors, lubuntu, display, radeon

I can get Lubuntu 13.10 to display my desktop on either screen, but it refuses to display on both  at the same time. Changing the resolution of a screen generally toggles which screen is displayed; using arandr does not solve the issue. My graphics card is a Radeon HD6380G; I've had ubuntu 12.04 working on this before so I'm absolutely stumped

edit:

I actually got this to work using the proprietary drivers, which is the opposite of what most guides say:

```
sudo apt-get install figlrx
sudo aticonfig --initial
sudo reboot now
```

monitors work fine now

Comment: If you've fixed the problem, you should list the solution as an answer to the question and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I will now, it wouldn't let me originally because of my low reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this to work using the proprietary drivers

```
sudo apt-get install figlrx
sudo aticonfig --initial
sudo reboot now
```

monitors work fine now